# Why rxgraph show partial information when selecting the combo box?

Tags: ros, rxgraph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi~

I used rxgraph to see how gazebo works,
and I found a weird thing.

It showed all topics connecting to the gazebo node when
I didn't select any PATH combo box.

But when I selected the gazebo node of PATH combo box,
it just showed little parts of all topics which connecting the gazebo node.

[http://imgur.com/a/yGtDU](https://imgur.com/a/yGtDU)

I am wondering why this happens.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30519/why-rxgraph-show-partial-information-when-selecting-the-combo-box?/) by [Eric](https://answers.ros.org/users/2016/eric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's because you are filtering the graph to see only the topics and nodes whoose names or path start with "/gazebo/".

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2012-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2